# Laravel Query builder / Scope question here meet requirements for multiple conditions in the same scope

Tags: mysql, laravel, scope, builder

So I took over a project and now unfortunately the owners of my company want our entire search (the way this entire dang web app was built) to function differently.   Currently we have scopes to only active charters and then some other conditions (which will stay).  I now need to create an active scope that meets the 3 following requirement:

active = true and snooze_dates are null
active = true snooze_dates are not null but the $date passed in is not within the snooze_start/end
active = false and snooze_dates are not null and the $date passed in has a greater value than the snooze_end_date (charter will be activated at that point)

```
public function scopeActiveWithSnooze($query, $date)
{
    $qOne = $query->where('active', true)
        ->where('snooze_start_date', null)
        ->where('snooze_end_date', null);

    //OR THIS
    $qTwo = $query->where('active', true)
        ->where('snooze_end_date', '!=', null)
        ->whereDate('snooze_end_date', '<=', $date)
        ->orWhereDate('snooze_start_date', '>=', $date);
    
    //OR THIS
    $qThree = $query->where('active', false)
        ->where('snooze_end_date', '!=', null)
        ->whereDate('snooze_end_date', '<=', $date);
}
```

This is the idea of the scope but how can I make all conditions work?

Comment: So you need the 3 queries in one?  you can use a function as parameter in the where function: `->where(function ($q) use ($date) {}) ` on `$q` you can use `where()` and `orWhere()`

Comment: Check out the documentation for "Logical Grouping": https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping. It lets you do `return $query->where(function($subQuery){ ... })->orWhere(function($subQuery){ ... })->orWhere(function($subQuery){ ... });`, replacing each of the `...` with your where clause groups.

Comment: Please edit the title so it describes the problem briefly

Answer (score 3):

Use logical grouping for that

```
public function scopeActiveWithSnooze($query, $date)
{
    return $query->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('active', true)
            ->whereNull('snooze_start_date')
            ->whereNull('snooze_end_date');
    })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($date) {
        $query->where('active', true)
            ->whereNotNull('snooze_end_date')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($date) {
                $query->whereDate('snooze_end_date', '<=', $date)
                    ->orWhereDate('snooze_start_date', '>=', $date);
            });
    })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($date) {
        $query->where('active', false)
            ->whereNotNull('snooze_end_date')
            ->whereDate('snooze_end_date', '<=', $date);
    });
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't `function($query) {` give a problem because the $query variable is present in the scope?

Comment: I feel so dumb but yea logical grouping make soooooo much sense.  Thank you so much this should be an easy fix.